# Simplifying noisy data for plotting and changing plot dimensions (horizontal)

Tags: r, plot, average, smoothing, moving-average

**Data Background:** I have a large data frame (50,000 values, 10,000 when removing NAs) for a single chromosome. I am trying to plot a fixation index (Y-range: 0-1)(data$'N:S') across chromosomal positions (X-range: 0-250,000,000)(data$'pos'). I used a program (popoolation 2) to calculate sliding window averages for a window size of 50,000 and a step size of 10,000, resulting in my data. However, on R this is too noisy and it comes out looking like a blob. When I zoom in by changing the x-axis so each tick is 500,000 separation, you can see the trends nicely. I think I can fix this on a large chromosomal stage by increasing the area of the x-axis and finding a way to simplify the data.

**Currently I have:** All my data plotted, simple mean, StandDevs (color coded)

**I am trying to figure out two things.**

**1** Is there a way to extend the X-axis to stretch out the length of it. I don't want to change the markers on it or what it displays, I want to make the actual length longer. (Example, if I had a graph on a piece of paper that showed an x-Axis of 1-10 on a 2" area, I would want to increase the area to 5", not change the defined limits to say 1-100. so, not xlim function)

**2** Simplify the data in some way. I was thinking easiest would be a smoothed or rolling mean across the data. When I use rollmean() or smooth() it separates my data from the x-axis, so it only extends to the 8,000 points and when I plot it doesn't go across the whole chromosomal graph with the rest of my data. Someone mentioned there may be away to instead randomly sample data to simplify it?
**2B** If I get a trendline to work, can I color code it so that part of it that is 1 or 2 standard deviations above the mean can be a different color if I mute my actual background data and remove its color.

**R Code**

Image 1-Plotting All Positions

```
plot(data$'Pos',data$'N:S', ylim=c(0,0.5), col=data$Colour)
```

Image 3-I tried both

```
lines(smooth(datatest$`N:S`), type="l", col = "blue", lwd = 1)
```

and

`rolling = rollmean(datatest$`N:S`, 9)
lines(rolling, type="b", col = "purple", lwd = 1)`

Image 2-Plotting a Nice Subsection-- why I want to extend X-axis

```
plot(data$'Pos',data$'N:S', ylim=c(0,0.5), xlim=c(163000000,165000000), col=data$Colour)
```

Notes: 
If it matters, my graph has colored points due to color coded regions related to means and Standard Dev.

```
data$Colour[data$'N:S'>=data_SD1above]="orange"
```

Also, the only difference between data and datatest was that datatest had NA values removed.

[Image 1: All Positions-Messy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DesGS.jpg)

[Image 2: Zoomed In to see trends](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAyTD.jpg)

[Image 3: All positions with the two attempted trendlines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKeGk.jpg)

Comment: I would suggest using `ggplot` or `plotly` - makes for much nicer, readable plots. For 1, you could set the `height` and `width` parameter. E.g. for `ggplot` and saving to a pdf using `ggsave` set the dimensions to get the aspect ratio you want and also the resolution (`dpi`).

Answer (score 0):

So it seems like that you want to resize the width of the graph for the visualization.

if you use Rstudio, there is an output option which changes the width and height of the graph.

if you use the console, you can save your plot with width and height. for example

```
png("mychromosome.png".width=1000,height=300)
plot(..blah..blah..)
dev.off()
```

I hope it will help you.